# Integration of detectTransformGestures (zoom...) with brand new ViewPager from latest Jetpack Compose libraries (v1.4.3)

Tags: android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, material3

With latest Jetpack compose library, view pager integration is quite straight forward.

But when I add a modifier with the `detectTransformGestures` method, as defined in the [official android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputScope).detectTransformGestures(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function4));
the zoom, translation and rotation are OK but we cannot change page anymore.

I am using jetpack compose BOM 2023.05.01:
`implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.05.01')`
and material3 libraries.

I have put a simple example that shows the problem (see code below).

I would expect that when reaching the left or right border of a given image, the next one would show up, but instead I can "push" the image out of the screen and am blocked on the initial page forever.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun PagerExamplePage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val items = listOf(Icons.Outlined.Person, Icons.Outlined.RocketLaunch, Icons.Outlined.PhotoCamera)

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    HorizontalPager(
        pageCount = items.size,
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize().wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center),
        key = { it }
    ) { page -> OneImage(items, page) }
}

@Composable
private fun OneImage(
    items: List<ImageVector>,
    page: Int
) {
    var zoom by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
    var angle by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    val modifierNoGesture = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant)

    val imageModifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTransformGestures(
                onGesture = { gestureCentroid, gesturePan, gestureZoom, gestureRotate ->
                    val oldScale = zoom
                    val newScale = (zoom * gestureZoom).coerceIn(1f..10f)

                    offset = (offset + gestureCentroid / oldScale).rotateBy(gestureRotate) -
                            (gestureCentroid / newScale + gesturePan / oldScale)
                    angle += gestureRotate
                    zoom = newScale
                }
            )
        }
        .graphicsLayer {
            translationX = -offset.x * zoom
            translationY = -offset.y * zoom
            scaleX = zoom
            scaleY = zoom
            rotationZ = angle
            TransformOrigin(0f, 0f).also { transformOrigin = it }
        }

    Icon(
        imageVector = items[page], contentDescription = "",
        //  Using this modifier, zoom is OK but we are "blocked" on the first page
        modifier = imageModifier
        // with this one, pager is OK but we have no zoom 
        // modifier = modifierNoGesture
    )
}
```